# Could not retrieve data from URL from facebook with like button

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I was using like button in my website with properly configured app. But right after I copied this code for Google Analytics:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-40129864-4', 'klejner.pl');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Facebook started to having problems with retriving data from my website (like thumbnails). After linking my site inside facebook wall I can see only url, nothing more.

Here is info from Open Graph Object Debugger which shows me that facebook is scraping my website but has problem with collectiong data:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fklejner.pl%2Fobrazek%2FdUFNwX%2Fwiezyczka-v20

I have already tried to solve this problem with:

- adding information about platfrom (website) in my app settings
- adding my site URL to Valid OAuth redirect URIs (in Advanced tab)
- deleting old and creating new app
- deleting Google Analitycs code

No success yet.

Comment: You have no meta tags in your header on http://klejner.pl/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved. 
It was not the Google Analytics code. The problem was with encoding. In mysteroius way my Notepad++ changed previous used UTF-8 encoding without BOM into normal UTF-8. When i changed it back, my script started to work.

And thanks Control Alt Design, i have to change that.